# Returning a character array error, weird return value

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am writing a series of stack manipulation functions in C, and I am having an issue with `pop`. The tester file requires a return of `ItemT` where `ItemT` is just the `define` for `char *`.

```
ItemT popStack(StackP stackPtr) {
  if (isEmptyStack(stackPtr)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nERROR: Empty stack...\n");
    return NOTHING;
  }
  else {
    ItemT item = *((stackPtr->items));
    (stackPtr->top)--;
    (stackPtr->count)--;
    --(stackPtr->items);
    return item;
  }
}
```

`items` of `(stackPtr->items)` is a `ItemT *`, or a `char **`

in the line `ItemT item = *((stackPtr->items));` I am trying to get the `char *` that `stackPtr->items` is pointing to and set it to the variable `item` and then return `item`.

My bug is the `return`, when the tester program calls pop and tries to display the value returned by `popStack()` what is displayed is this:

[image]

The stack is full of `char *` and peek works just fine. It is just pop here and seems to not work.

I just assume that that is bad data or random values stored in empty memory addresses. Thus, I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any way someone can explain to me what is wrong here? and is there an issue with my method of decrementing the `items` in the struct?

EDIT 1:

the call to popStack() looks something like:

`printf("%s\n", popStack(stackP));` where `stackP` is the pointer to the struct that contains all the info. You can ignore `top` and `count` because they work effectively. The `--(stackPtr->items)` I have just learned is absolutely ineffective.

Comment: Post more code please, and don't do this `*((stackPtr->items))` it's not very easy to follow, instead just `stackPtr->items[0]`.

Comment: I literally just figured that out. Now I am working on trying to get the logic right. I've been incrementing the pointer.

Comment: Also, isn't that what `top` is for, so shouldn't it be `item = stackPtr->items[stackPtr->top];` and don't alter the pointer, or else how are you going to free it?

Comment: @iharob I added a little more, i hope that helps. Thanks for the bracket info im working with that now and seeing if i can't get rid of that bad data.

Comment: i use count for something else, just a something i added for ease that i won't go into. The way i see it I could use `top` or `count` and it would work the same as long as i use the logic correctly.

Comment: `--(stackPtr->items);` is completely wrong. You have no idea where the next block of data in the stack is, and it may or may not be in the address before the current `stackPtr->items`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change this

```
ItemT item = *((stackPtr->items));
```

to

```
ItemT item = stackPtr->items[stackPtr->top];
```

and remove this

```
--(stackPtr->items);
```

Comment: did that, but now i'm working at a segmentation fault because of bad logic, alot of my program needs a little fine tuning because of adding the change you suggested, but it is putting me in the right direction after five hours. thanks @iharob